# Spring security ldap with struts 1.1 integration

Tags: java, ldap, struts-1, spring-security-ldap

Not able find out steps to Integrate Spring security ldap authentication in struts 1.1 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Add the spring.jar into your project
2. In the web.xml file, add the following piece of code

   ```
   <context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>
   /WEB-INF/acegi-security-config.xml
   </param-value>
   </context-param>


   <!-- Spring Security Filter -->

   <filter>
   <filter-name>Acegi Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy</filter-class>
   <init-param>
   <param-name>targetClass</param-name>
   <param-value>org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy</param-value>
   </init-param>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>Acegi Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter>
   <filter-name>AuthenticatedFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.security.AuthenticatedFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>AuthenticatedFilter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
   </filter-mapping>

   <listener>
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```

acegi-security-config.xml, is the spring security configuration file